# Why is ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'DZA' displayed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I wrote this code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# Create a copy of the data
data_corr = new_data.copy()

# Encode the 'banking_crisis' column
data_corr['banking_crisis'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(data_corr['banking_crisis'])

# Convert 'currency_crisis' to binary: 'no_crisis' (0) and 'crisis' (1)
data_corr['currency_crisis'] = data_corr['currency_crisis'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 0 else 1)

# Compute the correlation matrix
corr_matrix = data_corr.corr()
```

Why does it show："ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'DZA'"?

Comment: Please add a small example of input dataframe to your question to make it possible to help you.

Comment: Because your data contains, somewhere, the string "DZA" in a column that is expected to be a floating point number.